# Sound Through Speaker And Earphone both or from Speaker Only

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-silverlight

in UWP or Windows phone 8/8.1/silverlight 
i want to play sound through speaker only speaker event earphone connected or switch audio to loudspeaker on button click  or in both any thing may possible?
please suggest me a solution

Comment: UWP, windows phone 8.1 are similar, but windows phone 8/ silverlight is another different story, what exactly do you want?

Comment: mainly for windows phone silverlight app

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT for windows phone 8.1 silverlight

Comment: it works in UWP , View this solution 



https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f50d21bc-61d7-4058-ba6c-4da6c9b90c95/route-media-audio-to-speakereven-if-headset-is-connect-uwp?forum=wpdevelop